# Agglomerative Clustering from Pearson Matrix in Excel File

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Ello. Looking to apply Agglomerative Clustering from sklearn.cluster in Python to an Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx)

```
 import openpyxl
 # Get Data from Excel Spreadsheet
 data = openpyxl.load_workbook('matrix2.xlsx')

 import numpy as np
 # Pick the worksheet you want
 sheet = data.active

 # Grab Data from Spreadsheet
 X = np.array([[i.value for i in j] for j in sheet['A1': 'BT71']])
 from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
 ac = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=12,
 affinity="pearson_affinity",
   linkage="complete")
```

After that, it all gets a bit much and I need a lie down and a cold flannel. matrix2.xlsx is a little spreadsheet with one worksheet named matrix, only 71 columns by 71 rows, with values between 0.0 and 1.0 as you'd expect from Pearson.

Ta, muchly for any assistance. I'm guessing the number of clusters at a maximum 12 as I've already rendered a heat map in Excel - would like to identify clusters and centroids, and hopefully make a pretty dendrogram.

Answer (score 0):

The AgglomerativeClustering function expects the raw input data, or a *distance* matrix if you choose "precomputed".

Right now, you are computing Pearson of Pearson.

Comment: Ta muchly Anony-Mousse, that gets me one step closer and I'm grateful to you.